# Node.js MongoDB Find all by _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to do this, works fine in mongo console

```
> db.user.find({"_id": {$in: [ObjectId("55efa50a6f002c766e8b4571") ,ObjectId("56e9cc2d6f002ccf028b4567")]}});
```

in NodeJs, but this does not work:

```
user_collection.find({"_id":{$in: [new ObjectId("55efa50a6f002c766e8b4571"), new ObjectId("56e9cc2d6f002ccf028b4567")]} })....
```

I am using native mongodb driver

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dbConfig = config.get('Autenthication.dbConfig');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

MongoClient.connect(dbConfig.url, function (err, db) {
    var user_collection = db.collection('user');
    user_collection.find({"_id":{$in: [new ObjectId("55efa50a6f002c766e8b4571")]} }, {_id:true, name:true, email:true ,emailAccount:true, idFacebook:true}).each(function(err, user) {

     //code code code

    });
});
```

the `[new ObjectId("55efa50a6f002c766e8b4571")]` is example

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Or just no results?

Comment: Define "does not work". 1. Are you connected to the database and have verified this with other queries? 2. Are you sure you have the correct collection name? 3. Are you returning to callback or Promise? Did you in fact forget to do either? You probably need to show more context around the actual code you are calling.

Comment: I get no error, just no results.

Comment: what would you get if you do user_collection.find(yourquery).toArray(function(error, results){console.log(error);console.log(results};)

Comment: I am using each

 user_collection.find({"_id":{$in: [new ObjectId("55efa50a6f002c766e8b4571")]} }, {_id:true, name:true, email:true ,emailAccount:true, idFacebook:true}).each(function(err, user) {

//code here

});

Comment: If I change the find to findOne  it works, but I need find all

Comment: It' helps if you actually put your code "in your question". Show us a small listing that connects to the database, selects your collection and attempts to get the data. Also include your current nodejs version.

Comment: @OtavioCarvalho where .each function is from? it is surly not a native javascript function. if you put a console.log in the callback, is it even triggered? if it is, what you get if you log err and user?

Comment: [`.each()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#each) is long deprecated and due for removal. You really want either [`.forEach()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#forEach) or [`.toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray), where the latter returns all results into an array at once.

Comment: In all reality you really should be using promises and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax in any new development, rather than your current system of callbacks. And `.toArray()` for small resutls, or dealing with the returned cursor as a [node stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) for anything bigger.

Comment: @OtavioCarvalho change function(err, user) to function(user, err) and try again

Comment: @NeilLunn forEach works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

did you try this way

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
user_collection.find({"_id":{$in: ["55efa50a6f002c766e8b4571", "56e9cc2d6f002ccf028b4567"]} })....
```

Comment: Yep, the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Try not to define the objects inside the query. Pass it as another variable.

e.g.:

```
var id1 = "55efa50a6f002c766e8b4571";
user_collection.find({"_id":{$in: [id1]} })
....
```